# PHP: Character escaping not working with double quotes unless there is a <pre> tag?

Tags: php, string

Please can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
//outputs : Hi, my name is Jackal I like PHP
<?php
echo "Hi, my name is Jackal \nI like PHP";
?>
```

Whereas if I use pre tag

```
//outputs: Hi, my name is Jackal
//         I like PHP
<pre>
<?php
echo "Hi, my name is Jackal \nI like PHP";
?>
```

Can someone please explain why character escaping isn't working?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

PHP **is** interpreting that line break.  Look in the source code of the webpage.  You'll see that you have 2 lines in the source.

However, HTML handles line breaks differently.  To perform a line break in HTML, use the `<br>` tag.  This will make the HTML output over 2 lines on the webpage itself.  However, in the source code, it will still appear as a single line (unless you add that line break).

What `<pre>` is doing is telling the HTML engine to output the exact string as-is since the text is preformatted, including interpreting that line break.  Also note, you should add a closing `</pre>` tag at the end of the block that is preformatted.

Comment: Thank you! It does appear in two lines.

Comment: Awesome, if this post answered your question, please click the checkmark on the left to make this your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have this in your HTML:

```
<p>Hello,
World!</p>
```

Does it appear on one line, or two?

Usually, the answer is one: whitespace is condensed into a single space.

`<pre>`, however, has the default CSS of `white-space:pre`, which does NOT condense whitespace.

You should `echo "<br />"`, or apply `white-space:pre` (or, even better, `white-space:pre-wrap`) to the container element.

Comment: Hi,
Yes it does appear in two lines. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because in your browser `\n` shows just a whitespace and does not appear as line break unless you use pre-formatted HTML tag `<pre>`.

e.g. following will display with a line break in browser:

```
echo "Hi, my name is Jackal <br />I like PHP";
```

or this one also:

```
echo "<pre>Hi, my name is Jackal \nI like PHP</pre>";
```

As you can make out that `<pre>` tag is for displaying pre-formatted text hence `\n` does show as line break.

Answer (score 0):

Character escaping is working. Look at the source code, there you'll find the new line. In  order to make it visible in a browser you need an html tag (`<br />`) or the wrapping `<pre>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<br>
```

is HTML.

```
<br />
```

is XHTML (recommended).

```
\n
```

is a newline in the code (works while writing to file, but doesn't output to the screen).

alternately you can use nl2br as below

```
echo nl2br("Hi, my name is Jackal \nI like PHP");
```

Comment: Why is XHTML recommended?  Older browsers do not support XHTML.  If you're designing for newer browsers, HTML 5 has more features.  If you're designing for a broad range of browsers, HTML 4.01 is a pretty good standard.

Answer (score 0):

The `newline` character in php actually `echo`s a new line itself.

However, the output of php's `echo` statement is still the source code of the web browser. Hence, the browser condenses all the extra line breaks and spaces. For example:

```
<p>Hello
    there</p>
```

outputs

```
Hello there
```

despite the white space. To get around this issue, use the `<br>`/`<br/>` tag to tell the browser to make a newline, instead of tell php to make a newline.